# Is possible to install Android on Samsung GT-S5220?

Tags: installation, samsung

I have a Samsung GT-S5220 without android, I want to know if is possible to get Android on it. So, is this possible? If yes, how? If not, there is any site similar to Google play?

Comment: Check on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) to see if your device has an unofficial port of Android (unlikely if it's not shipped with Android).

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to do this. This is a "dumb phone" with 20mb of internal memory (nowhere near enough to run Android) and the hardware is completely incompatible.

As for sites similar to Google Play, this isn't possible either. This device does not support downloadable apps.

You may wish to look into something like the Moto E. It is a very good Android basic device that sells for about $130US (price will vary by market).